# Nagios/NRPE how to check all filesystems mounted below opt

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I have multiple mount points beneath /opt/virt/img, each of them an LVM logical volume formatted with ext4 and containing a qcow2 disk image for a running VM.  I want to know when those volumes are getting filled.  Is there some type of check_disk wildcard I can use to save me from having to specify each one?

CentOS 6.3
NRPE 2.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
/path-to-nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -r /opt/virt/img
```

Comment: -r '^/opt/virt/img/.*$' - if you need to be more specific